# Everything about Legendre transform

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

The Legendre transform, or transformation, seems to have many properties which are useful in different fields. For example:

- It switches between Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism in mechanics / tangent and cotangent bundle in differential geometry
- It is linked to variational problems (e.g. action)
- It is linked to convex analysis
- It is linked to statistical physics (e.g. free energy vs entropy)
- It is a sort of Fourier transform for the tropical semiring.

Where can I find all about it? Is there a reference specifically about the Legendre transform and all its properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late but there is a really great expository article [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1147.pdf) and an even more basic article [here](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~skennerly/maths/Legendre.pdf). Both of these articles really helped me wrap my head around it.